# how to auto generate new unit test ant reports

Tags: java, junit, ant

I'm using ant junit to generate reports for my unit test,so lets say i have a unit test called `userServiceTest` so in `my build.xml` file i put the following :

```
<target name="UserServiceTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <test name="webapp.service.UserServiceTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
            <jvmarg line="-ea" />
            <classpath refid="Web Application.classpath" />
        </junit>
    </target>
```

now lets say i've added a new unit test class called `productServiceTest` is it possible to include this new unit test to be generated in my reports automatically?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<batchtest>` instead of `<test>`:

```
<target name="UserServiceTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                 <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
                      <include name="webapp.service.*ServiceTest"/> 
                  </fileset>
            </batchtest>
            <jvmarg line="-ea" />
            <classpath refid="Web Application.classpath" />
        </junit>
</target>
```